# How to copy text from Google Drive webpage?

Tags: google-drive, firefox

Basically, I try to download some file on Google Drive, and it tells me that a 'virus has been found' or something, and I cannot download.

Good enough - except, I'd like to copy this 'virus found' message as plain text for my notes. But, I cannot:

- This 'virus found' message is a popup of a div element (likely), hangs on for a few seconds, then disappears
- Text selection on most of a Google Drive is disabled.
- Google drive webpage, was right-click disabled too, so I cannot inspect element directly.
- If I open Inspector in Firefox with Ctrl-Shift-K, then if I'm lucky, I'll find the div of the popup, but by the time I'm able to copy it, the popup disappears.

So, how do I copy text from a "virus found" in-page notification in Google Drive?

Comment: Take a screenshot when the pop-up is active.

Comment: Troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in [webapps.se]. Try using Google Chrome instead of Firefox. This because there are Google Drive features that aren't supported in Firefox  like using files offline besides that there are some Google app features that in the past didn't work work in Firefox ( I don't know if they have already fixed) like edititing Google Sheets cells.

Comment: You might also try Microsoft Edge.